# Query with multiple OR terms in WHERE returns the whole table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Can anyone tell me why this SQL command does not work?
I have a form with multiple inputs i.e. (id)=> account number, then firstname, lastname and email. I want to allow the user to search anyway they want.

if I leave the code the way it is "with AND" .. when searching only for just the (id) then it will just display the ID row but it won't display the rest of the searches if I try to enter first, last or email, but if I change it to "OR", then all the other input boxes will work displaying the single result, but if I enter just the id "account number" I will display every single customer in my table.. why?
what am I missing so my code can search for all the inputs? 
Thank you

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$firstname = "%$firstname%";
$lastname = "%$lastname%";
$email = "%$email%";    
$id = $_POST['id']; 



    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM `Demo_Guests`
    WHERE  
    firstname LIKE :firstname 
    AND lastname LIKE :lastname
    AND email LIKE :email AND id = :id

    ");
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($result as $row){
            echo "<tr><td> 
            <a href=\"main_table.php?id={$row->id}\"> " . $row->id . "</a><br></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->email . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->reg_date . "</td></tr>";


}
```

Comment: When you use the OR statement, you need to be sure you don't have `firstname LIKE '%%'`, because that will match everything. You will need to build your query to only use non-empty values provided from the form.

Comment: @Jerry that is a pretty good piece of code you wrote there. I just saw it. I will try that tonight and see if I can accomplish what I want.. difinitely a different approach but I can see how it can totally work. For now I am just learning the fundamentals .. I will send another note tonight and tell you if I got it to work!. thank you

Comment: @Jerry one quick question.. why when I use AND, everything works, but when I add the id to the whole sql commands, it disables it all and it will just work for the id only?

Comment: When you use AND, you will only get results back that match ALL the criteria. So when you AND with the id, only the one record can possibly match.

Comment: @Jerry okay very well.. I will work on the code you helped me with tonight and see how I do. thank you.. Can I update you if any further help? if that's okay?

Comment: If you have a specific question about the answer I gave, feel free to ask it in the comments for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment above, which was:

When you use the OR statement, you need to be sure you don't have `firstname LIKE '%%'`, because that will match everything. You will need to build your query to only use non-empty values provided from the form.

What that means is you will have to build your query from the NON-EMPTY inputs from your search form, and leave out terms that would match everything in your table.

It might be good to start by going through the post data and lifting out the non-empty values, to put in an array:

```
$searchFields = [];

foreach (['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email'] as $searchField) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$searchField])) {
        $searchFields[$searchField] = $_POST[$searchField];
    }
}
```

That gives you a list of all the fields that the user actually filled in. You will need that list twice - once to build the query, and once to do the bindings.

```
if (count($searchFields) > 0) {

    $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `Demo_Guests` WHERE 0";

    foreach (array_keys($searchFields) as $fieldName) {
        $queryStr .= " OR " . $fieldName . " LIKE :" . $fieldName;
    }

    // ... the rest of the code goes here

} else {
    return "you gotta give me something to work with!";
}
```

Two notes: 1) I didn't make id a special case, and you will need to do that in your code. 2) `WHERE 0` is a lazy-man shortcut to you don't have to do any extra logic later to decide whether you need to add `OR` to the first term. It turns into `WHERE 0 OR firstname LIKE '%Alice%'`, which is functionally the same as `WHERE firstname LIKE '%Alice%'`.

Once you build your query string, you can prepare it the way you did above, then perform the bindings with the same array you used to construct the query.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($queryStr);

foreach($searchFields as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$fieldName, "%$fieldValue%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

As above, I did not create the code to treat the id field differently, but you should be able to handle that. If you had lots of fields of different types, you might want to change the structure of $searchFields to include type information. If `id` is the only exception, it's probably easiest to just use an if statement in each loop.

Added:

This search will return all records from the database that match ANY of the input criteria. So if the user searches for `firstName LIKE '%Ali%' OR lastName LIKE '%Smi%'` you might get back Alice Smith, Alicia Smith, Fred Smith, and Alice Jones.

If, however, you only want that search to return Alice Smith and Alicia Smith, rather than use `OR`, you use `AND`. The search will produce fewer results, so it is a little less forgiving for mis-typed names and so forth.

The only other modification to the code is that the lazy-man shortcut also has to change:

```
if (count($searchFields) > 0) {

    $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `Demo_Guests` WHERE 1";

    foreach (array_keys($searchFields) as $fieldName) {
        $queryStr .= " AND " . $fieldName . " LIKE :" . $fieldName;
    }

    // ... the rest of the code goes here

} else {
    return "you gotta give me something to work with!";
}
```

`WHERE 1 AND first_name LIKE '%Ali%'` is functionally the same as `WHERE first_name LIKE '%Ali%'`.

Note that in this case, if the user specifies an ID, you will want to ignore the other search fields entirely. Otherwise, if they specify an id and a name that do not match, they won't get back any results at all.

Comment: the code worked like a charm.. it totally changed the way I used to do my queries... I have not seeing this approach before.. I know now how to build it in the future.. I did remove the OR  and left it as " $queryStr .= $fieldName . " LIKE :" . $fieldName;" and then to bind the values I simply wrote it as " $stmt->bindValue(':'. $fieldName, "%$fieldValue%", PDO::PARAM_STR); " so it can search for anything that matches.. It would be pretty inconvinient to know part of the address, maybe not all i.e, but no records will be found because it is not a exact match.. any how, I learned a lot!

Comment: Yes, you were right to add in the wildcard `%` characters. I had meant to put those in. As far as leaving out the `OR`, you are going to end up with trouble if the person fills out more than one field in the search form.

Comment: wow. I just tried that.. it threw an error.. SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined .. that I was not expecting.. Anyways.. just added it and it is all good.. u are a total pro.. wish I knew u in person to learn from u

Comment: Happy to help! If you mark this answer as correct, it will help other people find this who have the same problem.

Comment: I tried long ago but I get this.. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score...  you have any channel or any way to follow you? I really need to be very good at this

Comment: one more thing since I have been working on this for a while now setting it the way I want.. if I put certain first name.. lets say me Andy, but my last name is Smith.. if the person looking for me does not know my last name and puts a different one, then the query you wrote will return all andys it has in it and everyone with the other last name the user entered by mistake.. where can I LIMIT 1 in the query? I see no where I can add it so it gives me a exact match.. can it be done?

Comment: If you need your search to match ANY of the inputs, you use `OR`. So "%Andy%" and  "%Smith%" will match every Andy (or Andyropovich), and every Smith (or MacSmithson). If you need your search to match ALL of the inputs, you use `AND`. In that case, all the returned records will have to match both criteria. But be careful with that, as you saw before, if the search includes the ID, the only record it can possibly return is the one with that id. OR is more forgiving, while and is more exact.

Comment: mm I see.. My company's system acts a little different.. how can they allow to search by first few letters whether first or last name and even by first few letters added to the input boxes, a bunch of results will come up.. so if I put "an" a bunch of people will come up with those two.. but if I try to put the first name and another last name, if they don't match someone with that name in the database, there no one will?? how can they accomplish that?

Comment: if I put OR, then I'll get anyone with "an" for first name and anyone who's last name is whatever I put.. if I put AND, to be honest, I don't even know where to add  "AND" i have tried a lot of different ways.. I give up.. and if I add " LIMIT 1" then well,  it won't give me several results to help.. so how can I go about accomplishing a search where  I can type a few letters i.e and everyone comes up, but if I type a name + a last name which is not in the database, then nothing will display... that is the hardest part of this I think.. thanks Jerry.. srry for so many questions. I need this

Comment: I thought about just increasing the "LIMIT 1" to a higher number.. what do you think?

Comment: I have modified my answer to explain how using AND would work.

Comment: so you changed from 0 to 1 I see.. I would have never known that. I will check it tonight.. Thanks Jerry

Comment: this is perfect and It worked just as I wanted it.. srry to ask so many questions but I am determined in master this back end stuff.. just one final question.. why 0 to OR and 1 to AND?

Comment: I think you would be well-served to find a beginner's guide on Boolean algebra. The WHERE clause in a sequel select is a simple Boolean test performed on each row. Once you are comfortable with the formal concepts of AND and OR you will be able to compose better queries.